# How can I create a dynamic measure or column for an array in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, measure

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TbqW.png)

I am attempting to recreate a similar chart in PowerBI as I did in excel seen below:

Here I have revenue per day. The chart shows the percent of days where revenue exceeds a fixed amount (100, 200, etc).

In PowerBI I know how to recreate the table that the chart is based on by defining a column, but it's not dynamic. I can't apply filters to change the column values.

I know I can apply filters to measures but when I try to replicate the formula as a measure I get an error, which I assume is due to the formula trying to return an array of values.

Here is my formula for the fixed column version:

```
table2 column = countx(
   filter(
   DayRevenueTable,
   [Revenue]>Table2[DayRevenueExceeding])
   ,[Day])
   /Total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this:

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 04 January 2022 | 102 |
| 11 January 2022 | 162 |
| 17 January 2022 | 180 |
| 02 January 2022 | 185 |
| 12 January 2022 | 203 |
| 05 January 2022 | 278 |
| 01 January 2022 | 353 |
| 16 January 2022 | 449 |
| 14 January 2022 | 500 |
| 06 January 2022 | 515 |
| 08 January 2022 | 582 |
| 10 January 2022 | 600 |
| 03 January 2022 | 618 |
| 09 January 2022 | 626 |
| 13 January 2022 | 626 |
| 15 January 2022 | 706 |
| 18 January 2022 | 765 |
| 07 January 2022 | 895 |

You need to first create a table with your fixed values. Basically is the same concept as creating a parameter.

Using that table as a reference, you can create your calculation around `Fixed Values[Value]`.

### DAX: Fixed Values

```
Fixed Values = GENERATESERIES(100,1000,100)
```

### DAX: Days When Revenue Exceeds Amount

```
Days When Revenue Exceeds Amount =
VAR CurrentFixedValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Fixed Values'[Value] )
VAR CountValues =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        'Table'[Revenue] < ( CurrentFixedValue + 100 )
    )
VAR AllValues =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ) )
VAR Calc =
    DIVIDE ( CountValues, AllValues )
RETURN
    Calc
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Are you able to apply filters to this chart as well? For example, if I wanted to exclude Sundays would the chart adjust?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the calculation to allow filters to impact both the table and the bar chart as you can see on the output image. Please mark this answer as a solution if you find it helpful.